# サイドバーのエクスプローラの背景色変更方法

Tags: vscode

vscode extension api を利用し、動的にサイドバーのエクスプローラの背景色変更する方法が分かりません。(extension.ts上のロジックで色変更をしたい)

ちなみに、静的に変える方法は、下記手段を知っています。
同様にプログラムで実現したいです

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
"list.activeSelectionBackground": "#a02e9b",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WorkspaceConfiguration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration)クラスの`update`メソッドを用いることで、VSCodeの設定を上書きすることができます。このクラスのオブジェクトは`workspace.getConfiguration`を用いて取得できます。

```
// 'workbench.*'に対応するWorkspaceConfigurationオブジェクトを取得
const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('workbench')
// 'workbench.colorCustomizations'の値を更新
config.update('colorCustomizations', {
    // set 'list.activeSelectionBackground'
    'list.activeSelectionBackground': '#a02e9b'
})
```

ただし、この方法では既存の値を考慮せずに`settings.json`を上書きしてしまうので、設定を保存したり、プロパティをマージしたり、いろいろ工夫する必要はあるかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます（回答早くて驚きました）試したところ上手くいきました！