# vscodeのエクスプローラ表示で、任意のファイルの背景色だけを動的に変更する方法

Tags: typescript, vscode

下記関連ですが、
[サイドバーのエクスプローラの背景色変更方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48716/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%81%AE%E8%83%8C%E6%99%AF%E8%89%B2%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

vscodeのサイドバーのエクスプローラ上のソースツリーにて、
任意のファイルの背景色だけを動的に変更したいのですが、実現方法が分かりません。
typescriptのロジックイメージとしては、こんな感じです↓
エクスプローラ上のソースツリー内でファイルXXXを探索し、
ファイルが存在した場合、ファイルXXXの背景色表示だけを変更する。
（また、凄い欲を言うと色もフェード出来れば理想です）